# Change site content based on user language

Tags: sharepoint-online, language

Hi we are tasked to implement automatic language translation on our new SharePoint Online site as we have international users that will access the site.

We already created our landing page which navigation and all contents are in English and lets say our China employees access the site it will change to Chinese.

Any help and suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I know this does not answer your question. But as we were faced with the same problems I went to a SharePoint User Group and asked the guys there. All of them told me to better have seperate sites for seperate languages. You will always have problems to deliver a consistent experience for every language. Everything has to be translated in time, what to do with Newsfeed posts?, how to monitor every change in every document... So they recommended to not to try to deliver every language in one site. Meanwhile as I am using SharePoint for longer time I agree...

Answer (score 0):

This is my opinion below.

You could create a multi-language website. Then in the master page, you could add custom code to get the current login user, get the language of the user, and redirect to the corresponding site.

More reference:

[Create a multi-language website.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-multi-language-website-da0b5614-8cf5-4905-a44c-90c2b3f8fbb6?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Answer (score 0):

*SharePoint UI* automatically shows text based on user language.  So, the problem is how to change the content to the proper language. Depending on the requirements you can solve the problem using different solutions.

- If you only have this two kind of users (English and Chinese) and the content pages are few, you can duplicate web parts and assign audiences (English and Chinese) to each of them. People are managed using two security groups classifying people based on their language and used only for setting audiences.
- Another approach is to create a subsite for each language and manage a team for contributing content in different languages, something similar to *variations* but more manual. The main site should be in English with a link to each of the subsites, letting the user click on her preference.
- The last approach I figure out is to implement something more complex from out of the box features like *variations* to some custom development. I do both and none of them are easy to manage.